# Deduction Guide for a template template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, parameters, c++17, deduction-guide

I have a set of structure's class as such:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo {
    T x_;
    T y_;
    constexpr Foo(T x, T y) : x_{x}, y_{y} {}
};

template<typename T, typename U, template<U> class Func>
class Bar {
private:
    Foo<T> foo_;
    Func<U> func_
    size_t n_;
public:
    Bar(Foo<T> foo, size_t n, Func<U> func) :
      foo_{foo},
      n_{n},
      func_{func}
    {}
};
```

And I'm trying to create a deduction guide for this class template...

```
// Doesn't compile
template<typename T, typename U, template<U> class Func>
Bar(Foo<T>, U, Func<U>)->
Bar<T,U,Func>;

// Doesn't compile
template<typename T, typename U, template<U> class Func>
Bar(Foo<T>, U, Func)->
Bar<T,U,Func>;
```

I'm not sure of the proper syntax for this when the template argument happens to be a template itself where that templated argument will be a function pointer, function object, functor, or a lambda that the class will store.

When I try to use `U` within `Func<>` it states *"`type name` is not allowed"* and if I remove it to be just `Func` without any template arguments, it states, *"argument list for template template parameter 'Func' is missing"*...

My intended use of `Bar` looks like this:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr T funcA(T x) {
    return x;
}

template<typename T>
constexpr T funcB(T x) {
    return x*x;
}

int main() {
    Bar bar1{Foo{1.0, 3.0}, 1000, funcA<double>}; 
    Bar bar2{Foo{3.7, 4.0}, 500, funcB<float>};

    return 0;
}
```

---

---

**EDIT** - This section is intended for user: [piotr-skotnicki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3953764/piotr-skotnicki)

Note: The above was a pseudo code with the same signatures as a representation of my classes... Now that I have access to my IDE again, here is the "real" source.

**Integrator.h**

```
#pragma once

//#include <type_traits>

template <typename Field>
struct Limits {
    Field lower;
    Field upper;

    constexpr Limits(Field a = 0, Field b = 0) : 
        lower{ a < b ? a : b }, 
        upper{ a < b ? b : a }
    {}
};    

template <typename LimitType, typename Func>
class Integrator {       
    //static_assert(std::is_invocable_v<Func&>, "Invalid callable");
private:
    Limits<LimitType> limits_;
    size_t step_size_;
    Func integrand_;

public:
    Integrator(Limits<LimitType> limits, size_t stepSize, Func integrand) :
        limits_{ limits },
        step_size_{ stepSize },
        integrand_{ integrand }
    {}

    constexpr auto evaluate() {
        auto distance = limits_.upper - limits_.lower;     
        auto dx = distance / step_size_;       
        return calculate(dx);
    }        

private:
    template<typename ValueType>
    constexpr auto calculate(ValueType dx) {
        ValueType result = 0.0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < step_size_; ++i) {
            auto dy = integrand_(limits_.lower + i * dx);
            auto area = dy * dx;
            result += area;
        }
        return result;
    }

};

//template <typename LimitType, typename Func>
//Integrator(Limits<LimitType>, size_t, Func)
//->Integrator<LimitType, Func>;
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

#include "Integrator.h"


double funcE(double x) {
    return x;
}

template <typename T>
constexpr T funcA_t(T x) {
    return x;
}    

// This Works! 
int main() {
    try {
        std::cout << "Integration of f(x) = x from a=3.0 to b=5.0\nwith an expected output of 8\n";
        Integrator integratorA{ Limits{3.0, 5.0}, 10000, funcA };
        std::cout << integratorA.evaluate() << '\n';    
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

// This was failing to compile... but now seems to work for some reason...
int main() {
    try {
        std::cout << "Integration of f(x) = x from a=3.0 to b=5.0\nwith an expected output of 8\n";
        Integrator integratorA{ Limits{3.0, 5.0}, 10000, funcA_t<double> };
        std::cout << integratorA.evaluate() << '\n';    
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

// Same as above...
Integrator integrator{ Limits{3.0, 5.0}, 10000, &funcA_t<double> };
// wasn't compiling...
```

Beforehand Visual Studio was complaining that it couldn't deduce template argument `Func`... and I don't know why...

I don't know what was going on... maybe Visual Studio was acting up... It appears to be working now... very odd...

Comment: The `U` you're passing for `bar1` is an `int`. `funcA<double>` is a `double(*)(double)`. That's not `F<U>` for some `F`. This can't work...

Comment: @Barry, the `U` shouldn't be an `int` it should be the `double` or the `template argument` from the `function object` being passed in... this is where I'm getting stumped...

Comment: Well, `double(*)(double)` can't deduce to `F<double>` either. You sure you don't want to just deduce a callable `F`?

Comment: Yeah, I was originally using `std::function<double(double)>` as this parameter before templating this class. Now I'm trying to template it, and to make it explicitly `constexpr`. My functions had the signature of `double func(double x)` but now they are templated as well. Single parameter only and returns the same type.

Comment: The last parameter to the class can be a function pointer, function object, functor or a lambda expression, of a single variable. The class will store it from its constructor and will invoke it within one of its member functions.

Comment: So just make it `typename F`.

Comment: If I just make it `typename F` then how do I retrieve the `type` from the `function object` that is passed in for this class's member functions? The function object that is passed is also being templated... I need to use that as part of the declaration to one of the member functions. Or would I just template that function itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the below syntax:

```
template <typename T, typename U, template <U> class Func>
```

doesn't mean that `Func` will have a single *type* template argument, the same as the second template argument `U` of a `Bar` instance itself.

It means that `Func` is a class template that takes a *non-type* template parameter of type `U`. If `Func` requires a type template parameter, that should become:

```
template <typename T, typename U, template <typename> class Func>
//                                          ~~~~~~~^
```

And a matching deduction guide:

```
template <typename T, typename U, template <typename> class Func>
Bar(Foo<T>, U, Func<U>) -> Bar<T, U, Func>;
```

However, `Func` remains a *template* template parameter, and accepts only alias/class/struct templates, and that will never match a function pointer type, nor a lambda expression. If you indend to store any callable object inside `Bar` instances, then use any type as a template parameter, and let the deduction guide deduce which is it:

```
template <typename T, typename U, typename Func>
//                                ~~~~~~~^
```

In order to make sure that it *will* be callable with an (lvalue) argument of type `U`, just put a constraint like a `static_assert`:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename U, typename Func>
class Bar {
    static_assert(std::is_invocable_v<Func&, U&>, "Invalid callable");
private:
    Foo<T> foo_;
    Func func_;
    U n_;
public:
    Bar(Foo<T> foo, U n, Func func) :
      foo_{foo},
      func_{func},
      n_{n}
    {}
};
```

[**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bEpHc8DKalRlT7pU)

Also note that you don't need an explicit deduction guide, as one will be generated implicitly from the constructor.

---

However, if you don't know in advance what `U` will be used as an argument to `Func`, then that shouldn't be considered as a problem in the constructor definition, nor in the class definition itself. It's a clear indication that the argument will be supplied from some external source, and at some place you *will know* and *will be able* to verify whether it fits the callable or not.

For sure, you should not be trying to deduce the exact signature of a callable object. It's useless in practice and most probably means there's a flaw in your design.

That is, once you eventually know what type of an argument is used, put a `static_assert` there, e.g.:

```
template <typename ValueType>
constexpr auto calculate(ValueType dx) {
    static_assert(std::is_invocable_v<Func&, ValueType&>, "Invalid value type");
    ValueType result = 0.0;
    // ...
    return result;
}
```

Alternatively, you can make `calculate` SFINAE-friendly with `std::enable_if_t` or `requires`:

```
template <typename ValueType>
constexpr auto calculate(ValueType dx)
    -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_v<Func&, ValueType&>, ValueType> {
    ValueType result = 0.0;
    // ...
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Your example is good, but the member `n_` is not `U`, it is `size_t`. The `T` is the type that the templated struct `Foo` will use, `U` is supposed to be the type that the `function objects`, `function pointers`, `functors`, `lambdas` will use when they are passed into the constructor, and this is needed for the return types of `Bar`s member functions... `U Bar::someInternalFunc()`. If that makes sense to you? They need to match in types.

Comment: However, this class doesn't know anything about those function objects until they are passed into the constructor...

Comment: @FrancisCugler I thought `size_t` was a typo, hence I suggested to use an implicit deduction guide. If it's not a typo, then just write a custom deduction guide.

Comment: That's what I was trying to do, and I'm having a hard time getting it to work properly... I'm not completely familiar with the syntax...

Comment: @FrancisCugler Then what's the point in forcing `size_t` in the constructor when you actually want some `U` there ?

Comment: I don't need the `U` in the constructor. It needs to be a part of the template for the class's members, their parameters and returns types. These types have to match the type of the templated function objects if that makes sense...

Comment: Bar has member functions that will both return a type and one of them takes a type, that type has to be the same from the templated function objects that are passed in such as `funcA` in the example. If funcA takes a double, then `Bar`'s member functions have to take that and will return that.

Comment: You seem to be missing one thing. You rarely need to know the signature of a callable object. All you actually want is to know if it is invocable with the arguments that you will supply. And you probably *do know* what are these arguments' types.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't be able to use `std::is_invocable_v` without it.

Comment: @FrancisCugler Show me where and how you call `func_`. Otherwise it's just guessing what you actually want.

Comment: I got my code to work in one scenario, but it fails in another... I'll add my code below the original part in an edit section.

Comment: For some reason, Visual Studio was failing to deduce the template argument for `Func`...   I had removed the middle `template argument U` from the example above which was `ValueType` in my real code... Even after removing it, Visual Studio was still giving me the same compiler error. I then updated this post here. I switched from using the `templated function object` to just using a `function object`... to get the console results because I knew that version of it worked... Then when I used the templated type, to get the compiler error, it started to work... Very odd...

Comment: The only thing that I can think of, is maybe when I did a clean build and rebuilt the project it removed old stale code that was generating the compiler errors... So for over 2 hours last night, I was banging my head, changing code when I probably didn't have to... and never thought to go back to what I had from a previous point assuming that it wasn't working... I'm okay with templates, but there are some aspects of them that still trip me up at times...

Comment: @FrancisCugler Put `static_assert` in the `calculate` function. It's that function's problem if that function's argument does not match the stored callable obejct, not the fault of the class itself.

Comment: Okay, that makes a lot more sense!